# Can 1/2" drywall support recessed 7lb speakers?

Tags: speakers, mounting

I recently purchase some JBL SP8II wall-mount speakers that I would actually like to use in the ceilings. However these speakers don't come with a between-the-studs support of any kind (there is a wall bracket but it's a flimsy plastic that wouldn't add any support for a ceiling mount situation).

Do you think my 1/2" drywall ceilings would support these 7lb speakers without creating sag? The installation instructions are basically to cut out a 8"x10" rectangular hole in the drywall and then put the speakers in that hole, mounting them to the drywall.

Thanks in advance!